# Different validation rules on same entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, constraints, edit

The admin will be able to edit the users of his website, but not the password. So I've created this EditUserFormType :

```
namespace CAPUserBundle\Form\Type;

use CAPShopAdminBundle\Repository\DiscountGridRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class EditUserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class);
        $builder->add('discountGrid', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'CAPShopAdminBundle:DiscountGrid',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'placeholder' => '-- Aucune --',
            'required' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (DiscountGridRepository $r) {
                $qb = $r->createQueryBuilder('d');
                $qb->orderBy('d.name', 'ASC');
                return $qb;
            },
            'attr' => array("autocomplete" => "off"),
        ));
        $builder->add('isActive', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Actif' => '1',
                'Désactivé' => '0'
            ),
        ));
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('firstname', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('company', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('address', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('postcode', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('city', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('phone', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('fax', TextType::class);

        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'CAPUserBundle\Entity\User',
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'edit_user_form';
    }
}
```

But when i validate the form, there is an error with the plainPassword field from my User entity.

```
This value should not be blank.     edit_user   
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation

Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.plainPassword =
```

Indeed, there is a NotBlank validation constraint on it in order to force the user to set the password when he is registering.

My question is : how can I bypass this constraint for editing my User ? The password field isn't present on the EditUserFormType, so the plainPassword is useless. But I'm stuck because I use the same User Entity where is set the NotBlank value.

For the moment, I force the plainPassord field with :

```
$user->setPlainPassword('Ap@ssw0rd');
```

But this is an awful way to bypass the constraint...

Comment: I believe you cannot bypass this constraint because if you implement this logic, your application is vulnerable to CSRF attack. I am not sure about Symfony, but most of web-ready frameworks don't let you change / edit important information without extra authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) for discriminate validation rules.

In this case plainPassword in required for registration, and not required for editing.

So, set "registration" group for NotBlank constraint.

Comment: Didn't know the Validation Groups, this is exactly what I need, thanks !

Comment: Symfony3 -
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/conditional_validation.html#troubleshooting 
There should not be any validation_groups defined for the form.

Answer (score 0):

And I chose a completely different approach, renouncing the annotation-like validation rules in data models and using the constraints in the forms classes instead. For example:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $dateConstraintFrom = new Date();
    $notBlankDateFrom = new NotBlank();

    $builder->add('date_from', TextType::class, array(
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'bookform.place.date_from',
        'constraints' => array($notBlankDateFrom, $dateConstraintFrom),

        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'bookform.place.date_from',
            'id' => 'bookform_place_date_from',
            'required' => 'required',
        ),
    ));
    ...........
 }
```

I am used to this way of doing things and it's much more comfortable than annotations and validation groups.